# React Native RNFS delete file from download directory

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs, rn-fetch-blob

I'm trying to delete some files from the Android Download Directory.
I got the android permission to the external storage to do it, so this is my code :

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

...

await RNFS.exists(filepath).then((exists) => {
  if (exists) {
      RNFS.unlink(filepath).then(() => {
         RNFS.scanFile(filepath);
      })
   }
});
```

The unlink function works perfectly when I add some log in it. It doesn't `catch()`, but when I launch the same script again, the unlink still works while the file must be deleted, how is it possible ??

I don't understand what I have to do to completely delete these files...

EDIT :

I've checked the `react-native-fs` and it says :

```
Android support is currently limited to only the DocumentDirectory. This maps to the app's files directory.
```

So how can I delete files in the Download directory ?

Comment: did you try console logging the file path, are you sure you are passing the same file path?

Comment: exactly the same, and the file is found every time.

Comment: Did you find any solution??

Comment: There has to be mistake on your end or the package has been updated since you wrote your question, because I just tested this and results are:  ---- if file exists, it is deleted either from app dir or download dir.   ---- if file doesn't exist error is thrown.

So clear the cache, restart bundler and try again. Or maybe the file is somehow created before you try to delete it.